# Example of CHI Square test on Caesar Cipher?

Tags: cryptanalysis, statistical-test, classical-cipher

I am trying to get my head round the chi square test, when used with the Caesar cipher.
I started off using this formula,

$$ X = \sum_{i = 1}^k \frac{f_i · f'_i}{n · n'} $$

Where $k$ is the number of distinct letters in the alphabet, $f$ is the number of times the $i$-th letter appears in the first string and $f'$ is the number of times the $i$-th letter appears in the second string. And $n$ and $n'$ are the total number of characters in the first and second strings.

However when I run this, the highest value is not always the correct result. I was expecting values to be around 0.0650, however my correct answer is coming out around 0.0700. Is this the right way of calculating the Chi value?

The [formula on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson%27s_chi-square_test#Calculating_the_test-statistic) is a completely different formula, and the values should be near to 0 for the correct answer? Which has confused me.

Comment: Welcome on Cryptography Stack Exchange. I edited your question to include formulas, and also added a Wikipedia link. I'm not sure it was the right one - please check and feel free to edit again.

Comment: Is the objective to assert if the distribution of the $f_i/n$ is sufficiently similar with the distribution of the $f'_i/n'$ to support that a Caesar cipher with the same permutation table is used in both case?

Comment: One this is for sure: the given formula result in a number $X$ that depends too markedly on the distribution of $f_i/n$ to be appropriate for a traditional Chi-squared test.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'll assume that the objective is to assert if the distribution of the $f'_i/n'$ is sufficiently similar with the distribution of the $f_i/n$ to support that a substitution cipher (including Caesar cipher) with the same permutation table and same frequency of plaintext characters could be used in both case.

If $n \gg n'$, $f_i \gg 5$ and $f'_i \ge 5$ for each $i$, we can use the first sample as reference; the expected $f'_i$ is $n'·f_i/n$, and the usual Chi-squared test is now to compute (update: formula and condition fixed)

$$X = \sum_{i = 1}^k \frac{(f'_i-n'·f_i/n)^2}{n'·f_i/n} = \sum_{i = 1}^k \frac{(n·f'_i-n'·f_i)^2}{n·n'·f_i}$$

which should be distributed as a Chi-squared variable with $k-1$ degree of liberty under the null hypothesis. We can reject the null hypothesis (substitution cipher with same permutation table and frequency of plaintext characters, assumed independent) if $X$ is bigger than found in a table for Chi-squared confidence test. E.g. for $k$ = 27 and $X$ > 38.9, we reject the null hypothesis with confidence level 95%. CAUTION: we have disregarded the fact that letters in the plaintext are not independent, and this will tend to make $X$ bigger than predicted by the null hypothesis.

If some $f'_i$ (or $f_i$) are too small, an option is to aggregate the smaller ones into a single value (and reduce $k$ accordingly).

If fail to find a reference on what to do when $n$ and $n'$ are of the same order of magnitude.

Comment: I was running a CHI test for each shift in the Ceaser cipher against a sample of the English language. Then i was looking for a peak which would suggest which shift was most likely used.

Comment: @Lunar: the formula that I give should work, with $f_i/n$ replaced by the frequency of letters in English. The lowest $X$ will most likely be for the right shift, **if** the cipher is a Caesar cipher, and the plaintext in English (and long enough). In addition, the value of $X$ gives an indication on if the guess on the cipher is correct (of course the deciphered plaintext gives a much better indication).