# Using chi square for distinguishing between compressed and random data

Tags: randomness, entropy

I am trying to find some measurement for identifying and distinguishing between compressed and random data. I tried this first by computing the entropy of such data, the entropy value is extremely high (almost maximum) in both cases, so that way does not seem to work as a distinguisher.

I read about the chi square algorithm but I've never used it (actually I still have some problems with interpreting the results). Does anybody know if this algorithm can lead to better results?

Comment: I am not an expert in this, but the [NIST tests](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/ST/toolkit/rng/index.html) might do a better job.

Comment: Wikipedia has a pretty good description of [Pearson's chi-squared test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson%27s_chi-squared_test). The challenge, really, is coming up with a suitable null hypothesis to test; for example, even very poor pseudorandom streams will usually satisfy the simple hypothesis that the frequencies of individual bytes are uniformly distributed, no matter what test you use.

Comment: See also http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1287/example-of-chi-square-test-on-caesar-cipher

Answer (score 3):

The NIST tools are a good starting point.

There is no general-purpose algorithm that will always distinguish compressed from random data

However, if you want to try the chi-squared test, you can compute a histogram of the frequency of all byte values (how many 0 bytes you saw in the data, how many 1 bytes you saw, etc.), and then use the chi-squared test to test whether this appears to deviate from what you'd expect for uniform-random data.

Answer (score 1):

A late answer, but I recently had [cause](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/3744/are-picture-files-random-enough-to-be-usable-as-a-one-time-pad/48226#48226) to perform some entropy estimation and calculated some chis.

For context, in uniformly distributed random bytes, the target chi is ~255 leading to a p value of ~ 0.5.  As one definition of randomness is in-compressibility, it follows that you cannot differentiate a compressed file from a truly random one.  The caveat though is the level of possible compression.  A compressed file requires control and format structures within it that significantly differentiate it from perfectly random.  These control structures throw out the calculated p values in a chi test.  So some examples of compressed data:-

```
.zip p < 0.0001
.jpg p < 0.0001
.png p < 0.0001
```

Remember random data would have a p ~ 0.5 on average.  More specifically, a Kolmogorov–Smirnov test of these p values should see them uniformly distributed 0 to 1. So at this point my answer would be that yes, you can use a chi test to identify random data.

But compression algorithms have improved and I've found fp8 which is a [PAQ8](http://mattmahoney.net/dc/) derivative.  It's the most powerful compression program that I found that can be easily compiled. The same files now give the following chis having been compressed by fp8:-

```
.zip.fp8 p = 0.93
.jpg.fp8 p = 0.14
.png.fp8 p = 0.38
```

On prima facie evidence, these compressed files produce chi p values consistent with fully random data. So my final answer is no, you cannot differentiate random data from compressed data using a chi test.

Some further insight into chi and p might be had [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/48321/creating-a-k-bit-random-string).